# String manipulation can't keep up with sockets

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, sockets

I have one TELNET SERVER here, and this USSR Vessel v1.0 program is the client, it will be connected to the telnet server, the telnet server SPAMS, I mean sends the data very fast to the client .

(Well, originally the telnet server is a microcontroller that reads 5 sensors and the data will be sent back to the client so this should be quite slower than the C# program telnet server I use as a substitute)

The problem is this, I use regex to split the string coming from the server.

The string should be like this: Q0.00W0.10X0.30Y0.44Z99.00, you see, I'm erasing the Q/W/X/Y/Z and then store the values in a string array and then print them out into 5 labels, but I'm getting this error, see the screenshot below. I added a large textbox for debugging purposes. See my code in receiving the string via telnet:

[image]

```
public void OnAddMessage(string sMessage) 
{
    //Q0.00W0.10X0.30Y0.44Z99.00 
    string[] lines = Regex.Split(sMessage, "\r\n"); 
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line); 
        valuesStr[ctr2] = line; 
        ctr2++; 
    }

    ctr2 = 0; 
    m_lbRecievedData.Items.Add(sMessage); 
    tempVal.Text = valuesStr[4]+ "°C"; 
    frontVal.Text = valuesStr[0]; 
    backVal.Text = valuesStr[1]; 
    leftVal.Text = valuesStr[2]; 
    rightVal.Text = valuesStr[3];
}
```

Comment: why do you use regex.split instead of string.split or maybe even StringReader.ReadLine?

Comment: What's the error? The screenshot doesn't explain what's going wrong.

Comment: One thing I'd take out is `Console.WriteLine()`; if this method is truly being called rapidly doing IO is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replying. SETSU - so you did see my screenshot before? Anyway, I have uploaded it again. and you're right, console.writeline() slows down the process. BUT, string manipulation can't keep up still. The passing of string to the client (my C# program) is so fast. I'm not sure though.

Comment: telnet is a tcp connection so the tcp stack will wait for you to process data. The telnet client will be made to wait once the TCP window is full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs more clarification of what you want. As it stands, the code does nothing to accomplish what you claim it to be doing, namely "erasing the Q/W/X/Y/Z and then store the values in a string array".

Nevertheless, here's an attempt at addressing the problem phrased in the question:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private Regex regex = new Regex("[QWXYZ]");

private void OnAddMessage(string message)
{
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(message))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] splitContents = regex.Split(line);

            //do something with the parsed contents ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then again, I'm right, the C# program can't keep up the speed of the data transfer from the server. I just add a 100 microsecond delay in the server each  time it sends the data ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try the RegEx implementation from the Micro Framework

http://netmf.codeplex.com/

Here is a web cast explaining it!

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Net-Micro-Framework-v42-RTWs

It's arguably better because it allows you to match for an explicit amount of time and then resume where you left off.. something which is not easily possible by default with the Full Fx.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386890/String-Manipulation-in-the-NET-Micro-Framework